# How to convert C++ SaveFileDiolog info to LPCTSTR

Tags: visual-studio-2013, c++-cli, savefiledialog

I've been working on a c++ app.. and I figured out how to grab the directory name from a SaveFileDialog and combine that with text for a saving a bunch of files to the same folder, but the code ends up unassigned when I try to convert my new FileWithPathName to an LPCTSTR.

I have searched all over this site and can't seem to find a really clear example of what I am looking for. If someone can direct me to a link that is clear on this or tell me what am I doing wrong that would be great. ;-)

```
            FileInfo^ fi = gcnew FileInfo(saveFileDialog1->FileName);

            String^ fileNameWithPath = gcnew String(fi->DirectoryName) + "newName.txt";

            //LPCWSTR lfileNameWithPath = (LPCWSTR)(pfileNameWithPath[0]);  // get temporary LPSTR // fails to get initialized
            //LPCTSTR lfileNameWithPath = (LPCTSTR)(Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(fileNameWithPath)).ToPointer(); // data returned like Chinese characters. epic fail
```

Comment: This is C++/CLI, not C++. Changed tag.

Comment: thx Mr. Butterworth's. I was debating which one to use.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384865.aspx

Comment: Handy Link. thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple of different methods to make that conversion. You can use:

```
#include <msclr/marshal.h>
using namespace msclr::interop;
using namespace System;

String^ fileNameWithPath = gcnew String(fi->DirectoryName) + "newName.txt";

marshal_context context;
LPCTSTR lfileNameWithPath = context.marshal_as<LPCTSTR>(fileNameWithPath);
```

more [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/311259/how-to-convert-from-system-string-to-char-in-visual-c)

Comment: The key info was in the include and the top using statement. Now everything works. Thank you very much for those important items.